# Console.Redline reading second line

Tags: c#, console-application, readline

I have a simple program that tells the user to input *n* amount of students, foreach student an *x* amount of money is allocated. At the end, the program divides *x* by *n*, meaning the total money is divided equally by the students.

The problem is that `Console.Readline()` is reading the second inputted value as see below.:

[image: Console output]

This means that the user has to enter the values two times, each time `Console.Readline()` is called, which is obviously wrong!

Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double total = 0;
    int noOfStudents = 0;
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of students :");
        noOfStudents = checkInputTypeInt(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the students(" + noOfStudents + ") money!");

        for (int i = 0; i <= noOfStudents - 1; i++)
        {
            double money = checkInputTypeDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            total += money;
        }
        double dividedTotal = total / noOfStudents;
        Console.WriteLine("Total divided by " + noOfStudents + " is $ " + dividedTotal.ToString("F2"));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}

private static int checkInputTypeInt(string s)
{
    int numericValue = 0;
    bool done = false;
    while (!done)
    {
        if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numericValue))
            Console.WriteLine("The input must be between 0 and 1000!");
        else if (numericValue > 100)
            Console.WriteLine("The input must be between 0 and 1000!");
        else
            done = true;
    }
    return numericValue;
}
```

Comment: Take a close look at the argument `s` in `checkInputTypeInt`.

Comment: You call Console.ReadLine() both in the main and in the checkInputTypeInt method. You need to decide where to call it, one of them is redundant

Comment: oh, I was calling Redline() twice, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ReadLine twice:

```
noOfStudents = checkInputTypeInt(Console.ReadLine());
```

and in `checkInputTypeInt` method:

```
if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numericValue))
```

You should either send only the string to method like this:

```
  noOfStudents = checkInputTypeInt(Console.ReadLine());
```

and in your method just check that value like:

```
if (!int.TryParse(s, out numericValue))
```

in this case you should have the while loop in your main method.

or just use readline in the called method.

```
 Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of students :");
 noOfStudents = checkInputTypeInt(); // and you should change your method to fit no arguments.
```

**Edit:** final codes:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double total = 0;
    int noOfStudents = 0;
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of students :");
        noOfStudents = checkInputTypeInt();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the students(" + noOfStudents + ") money!");

        for (int i = 0; i <= noOfStudents - 1; i++)
        {
            double money = checkInputTypeDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            total += money;
        }
        double dividedTotal = total / noOfStudents;
        Console.WriteLine("Total divided by " + noOfStudents + " is $ " + dividedTotal.ToString("F2"));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}

private static int checkInputTypeInt()
{
    int numericValue = 0;
    bool done = false;
    while (!done)
    {
        if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numericValue))
            Console.WriteLine("The input must be between 0 and 1000!");
        else if (numericValue > 100)
            Console.WriteLine("The input must be between 0 and 1000!");
        else
            done = true;
    }
    return numericValue;
}
```

OR:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double total = 0;
    int noOfStudents = -1;
    try
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of students :");
        do{
        noOfStudents = checkInputTypeInt(Console.ReadLine());
        }while(noOfStudents == -1);
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the students(" + noOfStudents + ") money!");

        for (int i = 0; i <= noOfStudents - 1; i++)
        {
            double money = checkInputTypeDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            total += money;
        }
        double dividedTotal = total / noOfStudents;
        Console.WriteLine("Total divided by " + noOfStudents + " is $ " + dividedTotal.ToString("F2"));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}

private static int checkInputTypeInt(string s)
{
    int numericValue = -1;
        if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numericValue))
            Console.WriteLine("The input must be between 0 and 1000!");
        else if (numericValue > 1000)
            {Console.WriteLine("The input must be between 0 and 1000!");
             numericValue = -1;
    }
    return numericValue;
}
```

Comment: The readline() must be called from the checkImputTypeInt method, if I dont use readline() but use the argument s it will loop infinitely

Comment: well i said if you use s, read line and loop should be outside, let me write both codes, update my answer and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Try to divide the `noOfStudents` and `Console.ReadLine()` like this:

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
noOfStudents = i;
```